# NSurlsession is not working in Xcode8 with swift 2.3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, nsurlsession

```
let jsonObject:[string:string] = [
    "username":"sample",
    "password":"qwerty"
]

let url:NSURL = NSURL(string:<my URL>)!
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.addvalue("application/json",forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
request.addvalue("application/json",forHTTPHeaderField:"Accept")
request.HTTPBody = try!NSJsonSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(JSONObject,options:.prettyprintted)

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = session.dataTaskwithRequest(urlRequest,completionhandler:{
    data,Response,error ->Void in

    print(Response)

})

task.resume()
```

I did those things and i am not get Response Here. I used Xcode 8 and swift 2.3.

Comment: @EricAya : i asked in Xcode 8 with Swift2.3 Code. please help meee

Comment: print error also and check if you gets any error!

Comment: @Lion : i got nil response. i tried in postmen client and i am getting response there. Plz help

Comment: have you print error ?

Comment: @Lion : i got nil

Comment: give me your url if possible!

Answer (score 0):

Xcode disables all unsecured HTTP traffic from iOS apps by default.

So, I think the issue could be that you need to serve over https, unless you alter NSAppTransportSecurity.

As a temporary solution you can add this to Info.plist, to see if that helps.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

More info can be found here:
http://iosdevtips.co/post/121756573323/ios-9-xcode-7-http-connect-server-error

You should use ssl for production though.

Comment: This makes the connection insecure, make sure you remove this and use an ssl certificate before putting it in to production. If you are happy that this answer is correct please tick it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
let jsonObject:[String:String] = [
                "username":"sample",
                "password":"qwerty"
            ]

            let url:NSURL = NSURL(string:"enter url here")!
            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            request.setValue("application/json",forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
            request.setValue("application/json",forHTTPHeaderField:"Accept")
            do {
                request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonObject,options: .PrettyPrinted)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Error : \(error)")
            }
            session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { ( data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                print(response)
            }).resume()
```

The resources could not be loaded because th App Transport Security policy requires the use of secure connection.

[image]

Hope it works for you.